# Am I being Scammed

Tags: bank-account, scams, sugar-daddy

I met this one sugar daddy today and he is trying to access my Bank account with asking my passwords and everything. Then I checked where I met him from (Instagram) and I’m already blocked before Even giving him access to anything. I told him all he needs is my 8 digit code and he’s trying to say no he doesn’t I asked for it to be cashapped and he’s saying he doesn’t want to because he’s been scammed! I called the number I was also texting him on and it says say your name to be Connected to someone or something !!

Comment: Where did you meet him? on line or IRL?

Comment: Related questions: https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=sugar+daddy  Maybe we need a "sugar-daddy" tag.  :)

Comment: "...trying to access my Bank account with asking my passwords..." Straight to business. I like that.

Comment: Real sugar daddies use cash or visa gift cards.

Comment: "he is trying to access my Bank account" – yes, he is trying to scam you.

Comment: You should be aware that the term 'Sugar Daddy' does not mean 'someone who give you money', it means 'someone who gives you money in return for...certain favours'.

Comment: Seriously, what is with the increased use of the term "sugar daddy" these days?  Where I come from, having a "sugar daddy" generally implies *you are the scammer* (or at least morally bankrupt and willing to take advantage of a poor soul's loose chequebook.)  A sugar daddy is not just "someone who gives you money for no reason."  Usually because common sense dictates that *people don't give you money for no reason.*

Comment: @Steve-O I suspect it's supplanted "deposed prince with a secret fortune" and "you won the email lottery" as a premise for why a complete stranger is offering you a big pile of money. The old ones are getting pretty widely recognized. Presumably, this one will be too eventually.

Comment: @Steve-O going to somewhat disagree with your first statement, but "A sugar daddy is not just "someone who gives you money for no reason."". This can be mutually beneficial, it's not necessarily a scam or a morally bankrupt person taking advantage of someone. Obviously if it were they wouldn't call themselves that :p

Answer (score 14):

Yes it is 100% certain you are being scammed. Nobody needs your banking passwords to send you money. All the other stuff is just confirming it.